# How to loop through a command in a telnet session

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting. I have a manual work where in I need to connect to a remote computer through telnet and login to an application in that remote computer and run a particular command 24 times.

We don't have access to the remote machine so this is the only manual way the team is following.

Currently I am executing this manual steps:

```
$telnet ip port
LOGIN:::123::UN=someuserid,PWD=somepassword;
command_id=1;
<output>
command_id=2;
<output>
... so on till command_id=24;
```

I have tried automating this with below script runCommand.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
#Command line argument e.g - command_id=
input=$1
telnet ip port
LOGIN:::123::UN=someuserid,PWD=somepassword;
while [ $count -le 24 ]
do

ont=${input}${count};

count=`expr count + 1`

done
```

I am redirecting the output of this script to a text file.

However when I run the script, once successfully connected to telnet the next commands are not getting executed.

Any suggestions on this would be helpful.